Laravel 10 and autocomplete search
I am using laravel 10 and the bootstrap-typeahead.js to have an autocomplete search on a model, which returns a query totally different from the expected, apparently due to "ImplicitRouteBinding' ?
Here is an extract of my model:
    protected $fillable = ['word', 'slug', 'language_id', 'definition', ];
    protected  $table='words_test';

my autocomplete method in my controller:
public function autocomplete(Request $request) {

        $query = $request->get('term');
        $datas = WordTest::select('word')->where([['word', 'LIKE',  $query. '%']])->get();
        $dataModified = array();
        foreach ($datas as $data)
        {
            $dataModified[] = $data->mot_origine;
        }
        return response()->json($dataModified);
    }

and, finally the input & Jquery script included in my blade file:
<div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="translation_word" class="form-label">Translation Word</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead tt-query " id="translation_word" name="translation_word"  autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"/>

                    </div>

and ..:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
   
        // Set up Bootstrap 3 Typeahead with console logging
        var route = "{{ url('words/autocomplete') }}";
        //var language= $('#search_language').val();
        $('#translation_word').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get(route, {
                    //language:language,
                    term: query
                }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });

            },
            minLength: 3,
            items: 'all',
        });
</script>

I was expecting a returned list of words from the controller, according to the self explantory query from the autocomplete method above ; instead the query which seems to run is the following :
select * from `words_test` where `slug` = 'autocomplete' limit 1


can you show the output of php artisan route:list --path=words

GET|HEAD   words/create .......... words.create
› WordTestController@create
GET|HEAD   words/autocomplete ....... words.autocomplete
› WordTestController@autocomplete

For some reason, if I place the autocomplete route BEFORE any other route using the slug, for instance,it works like a charm...
I'd still appreciate a short explanation on this ...
If someone would take the time..
I'd then mark the post as answered
Many thanks

are you sure you posted all the response from php artisan route:list --path=words. can you post your routes file
